How to read json into variable?
How can I read a json into a variable to be used throughout http file, i.e as in:
# myrequest.http content
< {%
    import readFile from './readFile.js';
    client.global.set("DATA", readFile('data.json'));
%}
POST http://localhost/api/v1/model
Content-Type: application/json

{{DATA}}

POST http://localhost/api/v2/model
Content-Type: application/json

{{DATA}}


This can be done by using java bindings through rhino engine. When calling http use it with --js=Rhino modifier, i.e:
./ijhttp myrequest.http --js=Rhino

# readFile.js content
const FileReader = java.io.FileReader;
const BufferedReader = java.io.BufferedReader;

export default function readFile(filePath) {
    const reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    let line;
    let content = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) !== null) {
        content += line;
    }
    reader.close();
    return JSON.parse(content);
}

